# Mitsubishi eclipse convertible 2008 shaking problem

Tags: rough-idle, mitsubishi, shaking, eclipse

I have a Mitsubishi Eclipse 2008 has 96,000 mile .

When I drive, it doesn't really shake but when I stop at red light and the Geralyn drive it shakes a lot I have checked all the engine mount and the transmission as well.

Everything looks good and I did a tuneup for the car and I changed the spark plugs and it's still shaking.

What should I do to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Does the car shake when you are in park and idling?

Comment: No it only shakes when it's on drive (d). It doesn't shake when i drive it only when it's totally stopped

Comment: Hi Ali.  I see you awarded @edward the answer to your question.  You can also upvote the answer too.  This will reward Edward with more  reputation for taking the time to answer your question.   Thanks for using SE.  Hope to see you around.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say that it shakes when you stop at a red light, based on the context, I'm assuming that you mean when the car is fully stopped and the engine is idling.  (If I'm mistaken about that and you mean that it shakes as it comes to a stop, I'd suspect a warped brake rotor.)

I'm going to guess that the engine is running poorly at idle after the engine is warmed up.  This is a symptom for many kinds of problems, but three that come to mind are:

1. vacuum leak - somewhere, if a vacuum line is cracked or hose disconnected, you will often get poor/rough idle as a result.
2. MAF sensor problem - the Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor measures the amount of air coming into the engine so that it can be mixed with the right amount of fuel.  If the MAF sensor is not working correctly (for example, if it doesn't move freely due to dust, dirt or oil) the sensor readings won't be accurate and the engine will run poorly, including at idle.
3. Cracked air plenum - if the air plenum is cracked between the MAF sensor and the engine, the symptoms will be similar to the above but for a different reason.

You haven't said if you have tried to use an OBD scanner tool on it.  That would help diagnose this if you have or can borrow one.

Comment: It doesn't shake as I'm stopping or when I'm driving but it shakes when the car gets to a complete stop. There's a little vibration when The car is in drive mode with my foot on the brakes.

Comment: No only on drive

Comment: I wouldn't say it's one of the 3 if it doesn't shake on neutral.

Comment: Putting it in drive at rest adds a small load to the engine which probably causes the revs to drop and would make the shaking more pronounced. But yes, there could be other causes.